# difference between TaxonomyManager and ContentManager in Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity

I am trying to retrieve content block using sitefinity api.
I figured out two ways to get the content using c#
1. TaxonomyManager
2. [ContentManager](https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-search-for-a-content-block-by-title)

Please suggest betway to retrieve content using sitefinity.

Answer (score 0):

TaxonomyManager is used when you work with taxonomies - these are the Categories and Tags classifications (or any other custom taxonomies).

For getting the content of a content block you should use the ContentManager.

Comment: There is a custom content block that I was trying to read contnt from, but when I use ContentManager I was not able to retrieve content by title or guid. Alternately I've figured out the table in sql server and I am reading the data directly.

Comment: That's not ideal, what is the table name? is it sf_content_items? If so, the ContentManager should work. Maybe you can paste the code you were using that is not returning any results

Comment: ContentManager cmanager = ContentManager.GetManager();
                var contb = cmanager.GetContent().Where(cI => (cI.Name == "title of the content block")).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: instead of cl.Name you should use cl.Title